# HTTP Basic auth doesn't work with http.request, only with request because of missing sendImmediately flag

Tags: node.js, rest, http, authorization

I use the following function to do a basic HTTP auth against a REST API. Which uses the `sendImmediately = false` flag and it works.

```
  var request = require('request');
  var url = 'http://someurl.com/api/orders';


  request.get( {
          url : url,
          headers : {
              "Authorization" : auth
          },
          'auth': {
            'user': 'USERNAME',
            'pass': 'PW',
            'sendImmediately': false
          }

        }, function(error, response, body)
        {
          console.log(response);
        } );
```

How can I do the same thing using http.request, because i can't find the flag in the documentation furthermore the node-rest-client package is based on http.request and i can't use it either for my purpose.

Is my use case that unusual that a common module like node-rest-client would not cover it or am I missing something?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you stick with request?

Comment: libraries like https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client use http.request instead of request and say they support HTTP Basic Auth, but it seems not to work in my case which kept me thinking if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: You better stick with request.